# Is it possible to separate multiple values pulled in from a SQLite3 Row using Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a database row that links, as an example, the name Mike to the description blonde, short, glasses.  Current, if I were to run person.description, it prints out like this:

```
" ""blonde""", 'short', 'glasses',
```

Is it possible to separate these values and eliminate the extra '"'s?  Here are a few things I've tried:

```
    for i in person:
        for j in i['description']:
            print j
```

This returns each descriptive word character by character:

```
" 
"
"
b
l
o
n
d
e
"
"
"
,
```

Next I tried:

```
for i in plugins:
    print i['sets_kb_item']
```

This returned:

```
" ""blonde""",  'short',  'glasses',
```

I've also tried this, just trying to get lucky:

```
    for i in person:
        for j in i:
            print j['description']
```

But this gave me a TypeError:

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Here is an example of a row in the sqlite database that I am querying:

```
Name:        Description:
Mike         'blonde', "" """"short"""""",  'glasses',"
```

And here is the query I'm using:

```
 cur = db.execute("select * from person where description like ?", (query,))
```

My end goal is to have output that prints something like:

```
Name: Mike
- blonde
- short
- glasses
```

Ultimately, I need to revisit just what the heck went on when I imported these values into my DB, but is there anything I can do until then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a variable:

```
a = "\"\"blonde\"\""
```

Now when you print it, you'll see this

```
""blonde""
```

To remove the extra '"', I'd do this,

```
b=a.strip('\"')
print(b)
```

This would print:

```
blond
```

To separate on a ',' , you should do a split,

```
c=a.split(',')
```

Where `c` would become an array:

```
['blonde', 'short', 'glasses']
```

This gave you an array with your elements, now you can do any amount of processing you want.

So the total code would look somewhat like this considering a is your input string:

```
a=a.strip('\"').split(',')
for x in a:
  print(a)
```

I hope this helps with your problem.

Comment: Thanks very much!  Quick question, in your opinion, what would be the best way to do this if the strings I want are in person['description']?  For instance, if I do this with all of person, it returns some information I don't need.  I was thinking (in pseudo obviously):   for i in person:  for j in person['description']: a=str(person['description'].strip('\"').split(',')),  Unfortunately that threw me a typeerror.  Each string is currently in a unicode list so I was trying to cast it to string.  My brain has failed me!

Comment: Well honestly, I didn't really understand your question here. Can you elaborate it in better words?

Comment: I finally got it working!    `for desc in people:
        for i in desc['description'].split(','):
            print i.strip()`  This was a combination of what you gave me here and a few tries on my end.  Thank you, ishaan.  Now to try and get this cleaned up.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't reply earlier. I'm glad you worked it out.